# Restart Matlab Kernel

Tags: matlab, kernel, restart

I'm running a Python function in Matlab, and when I make some modifications in the Python function in Python, and then run in Matlab,
Matlab doesn't make the modifications, still running the function as it was before, even if that function doesn't exist anymore, I only overcome that closing Matlab
and restart again, but this takes a long time and requires me manually to close Matlab, is there any way to restart Matlab without leaving the interpreter? like in Python we can
restart the Kernel without closing Spyder...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Per the documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-modified-python-module.html), you follow these steps to update a python module.

1. Unload module
2. Import new module
3. Reload module *(syntax depends if Python is version 2.7 or 3.X)*

```
% Unload module
clear classes

% Import new module
mod = py.importlib.import_module('myPyFilename');

% Reload module (Python 2.7)
py.reload(mod);

% Reload module (Python 3.X)
py.importlib.reload(mod);
```